# datatables:jQuery loses serialize while posting

Tags: php, jquery, post, datatables

Can anybody help me with this? While alerting sData, it contains all the values I need, but when POSTing, it contains only data from current page in datatables.

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready
(
function()
{
    $('#form0').submit
    (
        function()
        {
            var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]');
            alert( "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+sData );
            $( {
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "html",
            "url": $("#form0").attr('action'),
            "data": sData,
            "success": fnCallback
            } );
            return false;
        }
    );
    var oTable = $('#gridtable0').dataTable(    
    {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "bSortClasses": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings )
        {
            /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */
            if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered )
            {
                for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
                {
                    $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    );
}
);
```

Alert: (2 checkboxes checked on 1 and two on second page)

```
id=2205&id=2204&id=2181&id=2179
```

POST: (2 checkboxes checked on current page)

```
id=2181&id=2179
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the relevant code. I think I can guess what's happening, but without seeing the rest of your code...

Comment: [This thread might help](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/185/submitting-forms-with-fields-on-hidden-pages/p1). It mentions a plugin called [fnGetHiddenNodes](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) which may be exactly what you need.

Comment: Here you got the whole code.

Comment: @Blazemonger - it doesn't help at all. Same effect.

Comment: All of your field names are the same in the serialization.  How is the server supposed to know the difference between `id`'s;  `$_POST['id']` will only return one number.

Comment: Is that really important? What is the difference between two id's and 4 id's in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [fnGetNodes](https://datatables.net/ref#fnGetNodes), use `$`

Example:

```
var sData = $('input', oTable.$('tr')).serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]');
```